# Hex to image in PHP

Tags: php, image, cakephp, webforms, fpdf

Any other way to create the image from hexadecimal number? 
I use a signature pad to get the signature and save it as an image and put in a PDF;
I have created the image (*.PNG) from the hex code(signiture pad generates the HExadecimal number); the image seems fine (I can open it and see it!), but for some reason this image cannot be put in the PDF by FPDF; however I can put any other images to my PDF by using FPDF; so I guess there is a problem with the image I created (HEX to Image). I created my image by the following code:

```
$binary = pack("H*", $MyHex);
file_put_contents("../img/Sign_Representative.png", $binary);
```

Do you know any other way I can create the image from HEX or any way I can handle this problem?

I appreciate your guidance!

Comment: I use a signiture pad which generates the Hexadecimal number; I need to use "pack" function to convert it to binary and then by "file_put_contents" I convert the binary to image! The image which I create by the mentioned code is fine ; I can open it and see it; but it seems (may be not compatible) with FPDF to put it (the image) into my PDF!

Comment: This may be overkill, but you could use the imagick library to create the image.

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.newimage.php

Comment: Doe it convert hex to image? the link doesn't say conversion form hex to image!I need to convert from HEX to image!

Comment: It can make an image of a single color.  I believe if you enter in a hex value into the sample code they gave, that will work.  If not, you could always write a few lines of code to convert the hex value to RGB.

Comment: The generated image is the exact signiture; but instead of "PNG" in the first row it has "BM†Ç"! Im using Topaz T-S460, So in this case that the header is not "PNG" could you please let me know what I can do? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that signature pad provides PNG-data in HEX?

Check generated file's content if the first row contains letters "PNG" (without quotes).

Tried yours and following and all provided data correctly back:

```
// test 1
$binary = pack("H" . strlen($MyHex), $MyHex);
file_put_contents("../img/Sign_Representative-1.png", $binary);

// test 2
$binary = hextobin($MyHex);
file_put_contents("../img/Sign_Representative-2.png", $binary);
// @src http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php#110973
function hextobin($hexstr)  
    { 
        $n = strlen($hexstr); 
        $sbin="";   
        $i=0; 
        while($i < $n) {       
        $a =substr($hexstr,$i,2);           
            $c = pack("H*",$a); 
            if ($i == 0) {
                $sbin = $c;
            } else {
                $sbin .= $c;
            } 
            $i += 2; 
        } 
        return $sbin; 
    }
```

btw, what kind/model signature pad you have? i.e. Honeywell TT8500?

Comment: Gerat man! The generated image is the exact signiture; but instead of "PNG" in the first row it has "BM†Ç"! Im using Topaz T-S460, So in this case that the header is not "PNG" could you please let me know what I can do? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So it may be a BMP-file. according to wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header

Comment: Also based documentation http://www.topazsystems.com/software/download/sigplusroadmap.pdf `SigPlus allows developers to convert the native signature file into an image format if the developer desires. Topaz supports .JPG, .TIF, .BMP, .WMF, and .EMF image file formats. `

Comment: Thank you man! I will try it tomorrow when I have access to the signature pad! But fpdf which I use for putting the signiture image into my PDFs does not support BMP!It just supports  JPEG, PNG and GIF. And I guess even I tried to convert the Hexadecimal number to "JPG" file and again it gave me "BM†Ç" header; I will try it tomorrow and will post the result! Your help is appreciated

Comment: I think you should convert that "on-the-fly" then to i.e. JPG from BMP. Here is one (untested) script to provide functions for that BMP >> GD >> JPG  https://github.com/hm2k/hm2k-php/blob/master/functions/imagecreatefrombmp.php

Comment: Hey buddy! It says the source file is not a BMP! I guess the signiture pad is not creating the right BMP file! However based on the link you posted "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header" It seems a BMP file!!!